# how to get certificate fingerprint when webview onReceivedSslError get called

Tags: android, webview, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

My app use https to conncet to server, for the server who is using a self signed certificate, webview will call its onReceivedSslError method. I need to response the callback and display a visible dialog to show the certificate info, especially sha1 and sha256 fingerprints. But I feel very confused to get them because the SslCertificate doesn`t support any getFingerprint method. Any ideas?

the onReceivedSslError method look like below.

```
 @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onReceivedSslError " + error.getCertificate().toString());
        // error.getCertificate().getSha1FingerPrint(); is not available
        // below methods are available
        // error.getCertificate().getIssuedBy();
        // error.getCertificate().getIssuedTo();
        // error.getCertificate().getValidNotAfterDate();
        // error.getCertificate().getValidNotBeforeDate();
        // error.getUrl();
        if (error.getPrimaryError() == SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED) {
            final Account account = new Account(serverUrl, null, null);
            SslConfirmDialog dialog = new SslConfirmDialog(account,
                    new SslConfirmDialog.Listener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAccepted(boolean rememberChoice) {
                            CertsManager.instance().saveCertForAccount(account, rememberChoice);
                            // Ignore SSL certificate validate
                            handler.proceed();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onRejected() {
                            displaySSLError();
                        }
                    });
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), SslConfirmDialog.FRAGMENT_TAG);
            return;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to get the X509Certificate

```
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
        SslError error) {
    Bundle bundle = SslCertificate.saveState(error.getCertificate());
    X509Certificate certificate;
    byte[] bytes = bundle.getByteArray("x509-certificate");
    if (bytes == null) {
        certificate = null;
    } else {
        try {
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Certificate cert = certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            certificate = (X509Certificate) cert;
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            certificate = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have the X509Certificate you can get the Fingerprints using the getEncoded() api of X509Certificate.

Courtesy : http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/net/http/SslCertificate.java#SslCertificate.restoreState%28android.os.Bundle%29

Answer (score 0):

SslCertificate class does not has a public getter for the underlying X509Certificate, we can only do this by hack. This only works for andorid 4.0+. So I solved the problem by a little hack like below.

```
 /**
 * SslCertificate class does not has a public getter for the underlying
 * X509Certificate, we can only do this by hack. This only works for andorid 4.0+
 * @see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/eAPJ6b7mrmg
 */
public static X509Certificate getX509CertFromSslCertHack(SslCertificate sslCert) {
    X509Certificate x509Certificate = null;

    Bundle bundle = SslCertificate.saveState(sslCert);
    byte[] bytes = bundle.getByteArray("x509-certificate");

    if (bytes == null) {
        x509Certificate = null;
    } else {
        try {
            CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            Certificate cert = certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
            x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) cert;
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            x509Certificate = null;
        }
    }

    return x509Certificate;
}
```